# Confirmation box is not working when trying to run a python script from an HTML button

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and HTML so I was looking for some help. I need to get the confirmation box working on this script. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The python script "disconnect.py" runs fine when the "Disconnect Service" button is clicked but I do not get a confirmation box.

```
<?php

  $output = exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/disconnect.py");

?>

<html>
<body>    
  <form action="/button1.php" method="get">
    <button onclick="$output()">Disconnect Service</button>
    <script>
      function output() {
        confirm("Are you sure?");
      }
    </script>

    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not calling the JavaScript function. The `diconnect.py` script is not being called when the button is clicked. That being said, to get the confirmation to display, try the following below.

```
<button onclick="output()">Disconnect Service</button>
```

Comment: Now I have another issue. If I click on "cancel" in the confirmation box, the python script still runs..

Comment: Right, as I mentioned before, the `disconnect.py` script is not being called by the button. It's being called when PHP renders the HTML on the server. You'll have to make an AJAX request to call `disconnect.py` from the client.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. How do I go about making the AJAX request?

Comment: You'll have to expose an API on your server that your client can call, and then do the disconnect at that time. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I've gone through this documentation but I do not understand how to put this together. Can anyone provide an example? Please help.